# Ionic Framework Run on IOS Device

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I tried to run my ionic app to my itouch device. When I first run, the app launch smoothly with no problem but when I try to re run again the same app. the terminal display this message "error: process launch failed: timed out trying to launch app"

I am using ionic run ios --device on the terminal.

Comment: this seems to be the same issue, https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-deploy/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

run ios --device starts debugging the App on the device. If you restart you App, do you need Debugging? If not, try to exit the debugging mode in terminal and restart your app on your device. Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Open the project by opening [yourAppFolder]/platforms/ios/[yourAppName].xcodeproj file in Xcode. And run the code in your phone just like running a Xcode project in the phone.